# Show 0 in count SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my result :

```
Year    matches
2005    1
2008    2
```

and this is my expected result:

```
Year    matches
2005    1
2006    0
2007    0
2008    2
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy,A.match_date) AS [Year], COUNT(A.match_id) AS "matches"
FROM match_record A
INNER JOIN match_record  B ON A.match_id = B.match_id
WHERE (score) IS NULL OR (score) = 0
GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,A.match_date);
```

I want to get zero as count in the years where score have some values(not null and zero, anything greater than 0) . Can someone help me?

Comment: Is this a typo: _"where score have some values"_ and should actually be _"where score have none values"_?

Comment: post your code for the current result you got with the two values, also in the table are they 0 or null?

Comment: the code I have posted get result of two values. In the table values are null, 0 and values greater than 1..I am here trying to get the count for 0 and null. In 2006 and 2007 there is no 0 or null...so I want to get them as 0 when I take the count

Comment: You need to post some more details of table structure.  I'm not sure how this runs at all as you are self joining onto the same table, but the 'score' field is not aliased.

Comment: please share the year range which you want to consider , irrespective of the fact that there is a entry in `match_record` for that year or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy,A.match_date) AS [Year],
    SUM(CASE WHEN score=0 or score is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "matches"
FROM match_record A
INNER JOIN match_record  B ON A.match_id = B.match_id
GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,A.match_date);
```

Assuming you have *any* data in the missing years, this should now produce your expected results.

If, instead, you need `0`s for years where you have no data, you'll need to provide the list of years separately (say, via a numbers table) and then `LEFT JOIN` that source to your existing query.

Comment: I think there is no need of self-join in above solution.

Comment: I have data for all the years. Thanks damien, This works fine for me.You have forgot to add END after ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

how about,

```
SELECT
            [year],
            COUNT(*) [matches]
    FROM (
            SELECT
                        DATEPART(yy, [A].[match_date]) [year]
                 FROM
                        [match_record] [A]
                     LEFT JOIN
                        [match_record] [B]
                            ON [A].[match_id] = [B].[match_id]
                 WHERE
                        COALESCE([B].[score], 0) = 0) [Nils]
    GROUP BY
            [Year];
```

Comment: @Tuttu, you'll need to explain your schema in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following is your table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM
(
    SELECT 2005 [YEARS],1 [MATCHES]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2008,2
)T
```

Declare two variables to get min and max date in your table

```
DECLARE @MINYEAR int;
DECLARE @MAXYEAR int;
SELECT @MINYEAR = MIN(YEARS) FROM #TEMP
SELECT @MAXYEAR = MAX(YEARS) FROM #TEMP
```

Do the following `recursion` to get years between the period in your table and `LEFT JOIN` with your table.

```
; WITH  CTE as
(
    select  @MINYEAR as yr FROM #TEMP 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YR + 1
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   yr < @MAXYEAR
)
SELECT DISTINCT C.YR,CASE WHEN T.MATCHES IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T.MATCHES END MATCHES 
FROM    CTE C
LEFT JOIN #TEMP T ON C.yr=T.YEARS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t table(Year int,   matches  int)
DECLARE @i int=2005
WHILE @i <=2008
BEGIN
IF NOT exists (SELECT matches FROM tbl WHERE year=@i)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT @i,'0'
SET @i=@i+1
END
else
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT  year,[matches] from tbl
SET @i=@i+1
END
END
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @t
```

[image]